# Mockito throws InvalidUseOfMatchersException for "verify()"

Tags: android, asynchronous, testing, kotlin, mockito

I wanted to test the API calls in my application. since the API calls are asynchronous. I am using mockito (`verify` along with `ArgumentCaptor`).

```
@Captor
lateinit var callbackCaptor: ArgumentCaptor<Callback<ResponseModel>>

 @Test
 fun testDetailsApiCall() {
    val mock: MyRepository = mock()
    verify(mock.getSomeDetails("xxx", "xxx", capture(callbackCaptor)))
 }
```

`getSomeDetails` inside `MyRepository` is invoking a server API call and sending the response back via `interface` callback.

But when I execute this test case I am getting the following error

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
Invalid use of argument matchers!
3 matchers expected, 1 recorded:
-> at xxx.xxxx.testDetailsApiCall

This exception may occur if matchers are combined with raw values:
    //incorrect:
    someMethod(anyObject(), "raw String");
When using matchers, all arguments have to be provided by matchers.
For example:
    //correct:
    someMethod(anyObject(), eq("String by matcher"));

For more info see javadoc for Matchers class.
```

If you guys can figure out the problem in this, it would be really helpful

Comment: Have you tried using `eq("xxx")` instead of just `"xxx"`? Since you're using capture...

Comment: @Demigod the method getDetails expects String arguments

Answer (score 1):

If you're verifying some method with arguments call, you use matchers (like `any()`, `eq()`, etc.) for **all** its parameters, or use exact values instead. You cannot mix both.
So instead of  `"xxx"` use `eq("xxx")`.

And also, I think you're using `verify()` method not as it should be used. It's semantics should be as following: `verify(mock).method()`.

Try changing your verify method to:

```
verify(mock).getSomeDetails(eq("xxx"), eq("xxx"), capture(callbackCaptor))
```

Comment: Wanted but not invoked:
AppDetailsRepositoryImpl.getSomeDetails(
    "xxx",
    "xxx",
    <Capturing argument>
);
-> at jp.pay2.android.sdk.network.apis.MiniAppDetailsTest.testDetailsApiCall
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.

This is the error I am getting

Comment: @droidev, that is actually an error in your logic, since your code didn't call this function.